# $\mathfrak{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ v.s. $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: notation, lebesgue-integral

I'm reading a paper that has referred to functions in and bases for both
$\mathfrak{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ and
$\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I'm familiar with the latter notation which consists of functions whose absolute value squared have finite Lebesgue integral. What does the $\mathfrak{L}$ notation mean? The paper uses it in the context of a vector-valued function and tensor products but provides no other context. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to the name of this set so that I can look further into it?

[This is the paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-11/issue-2/Converting-high-dimensional-regression-to-high-dimensional-conditional-density-estimation/10.1214/17-EJS1302.full) and the notation is seen on page 2807 if that is helpful.

Edit: Here's the context in which each appears,

> ...and the response $Z\in[0,1]$... start by specifying an orthonormal basis $(\phi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ for $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$....

> For instance, if $\mathbf{Z} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, consider the basis
> $\{\phi_{i,j}(\mathbf{z})=\phi_i(z_1)\phi_j(z_2)\,:\,i,j\in\mathbb{N}\}$,
> where $\mathbf{z} = (z_1, z_2)$, and $\{\phi_i(z_1)\}_i$ and $\{\phi_j(z_2)\}_j$ are bases for functions in $\mathfrak{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I think, if the paper does not explain this, then it is a poor paper.  I have seen two notations (perhaps not these) used where one of them is actual functions, and the other is equivalence classes under equality a.e.

Comment: (1) Does the Paper give the context for one & not the other ? (2) Could it then be a typo , where these 2 are Same ? (3) You could include some Examples from the Paper to your Post , which will allow other users here to make out some nuance.

Comment: @Prem, I've just added some examples. Hopefully that helps. If it is indeed a typo that is O.K. with me. I'm just concerned about accepting it as such since the $\mathfrak{L}$ notation appears in a different context to the $\mathcal{L}$. In neither case does it state explicitly what either means unfortunately

Comment: @GEdgar, thank you for your suggestion! I'll do some workings to see if I can make the equivalence class idea make sense in this context

Comment: With the given Context , I think **typo** is highly likely. My thinking (A) Here $L^2(R)$ is Common & the authors might have thought it unnecessary to "Define" that. (B) When using that , there might have been a typo between $\mathcal{L}$ & $\mathfrak{L}$. (C) When the Common Definition is not intended to be used here , then the authors would have thought it necessary to "Define" the 2 here.

Comment: @Prem, your points make a lot of sense, thank you! I'll take it as a typo for now